# SyntaxError:Invalid character in identifier

Tags: python

Hi I have just started with python.And while i tried my first program i was facing this issue:

```
python_mission = """
The mission of the Python Software Foundation is to promote, protect,
and advance the Python programming language, and to support and
facilitate the growth of a diverse and international community of
Python programmer
"""
print(“The word returned is: {}”.format(python_mission[25:34]))
```

> Error: Invalid character in identifier

Comment: You have curly quotes.

Comment: replace the quotation marks: `print("The word returned is: {}".format(python_mission[25:34]))`

Answer (score 3):

Notice how your quote in the print function is not a regular double quote, but an angled one... The type you get when your macOS's Settings are set to their default value to use them.

You need the quotes to be regular ones, so...

```
print(“The word returned is: {}”.format(python_mission[25:34]))
```

Should be...

```
print("The word returned is: {}".format(python_mission[25:34]))
```

Also you can uncheck "Use smart quotes and dashes" to avoid this in the future:
 [image]